# How can I install FreeBSD on a Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, freebsd, vps

I have purchased a VPS from Digital Ocean. I have console access, so no need to worry about the network not being configured at install time.

I have already tried using `dd` to write a small installer image ([image found here](http://mfsbsd.vx.sk/files/images/amd64/9/)) to `/dev/sda`. Like so:

```
dd if=/root/mfsbsd-9.1-RELEASE-p2-amd64.img of=/dev/sda
```

This made the VPS crash, so I tried again, but first I ran `umount -f -l /`. This seemed to work (dd wrote the image), but when I rebooted, to my surprise I was back in Ubuntu.

I also tried installing grub and grub2, but I could not access a boot menu for either via the console, even after setting the timeout and visibility options (I think that grub/grub2 did not *really* install, and the VPS just boots directly into the OS).

Does anyone have anything clever that I can try? I can wipe and restore the VPS as many times as I want, so give me any and all ideas that come to mind!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible to do this on digitalOcean.
Trust me, I tried everything (was also trying to get FreeBSD on it). They have the kernel/mbr boot options outside of what you have access to in their KVM set-up.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Let me know if you find anything, and I'll do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In case your provider allow snapshots, probably you could give a try to [fabrik](https://fabrik.red/) is a FreeBSD ZFS on root [image](https://github.com/fabrik-red/images/releases/) working in some providers like AWS, GCP, vulrt, netcup, lunanode etc.

This will basically remove the operating system of your VPC and use the one from the snapshot.